# Problems getting gr-osmosdr-git to import the correct version of libgnuradio-runtime

Tags: arch-linux, python3

I usually don't ask questions because I find if you search enough you can find the answer, but this one has me stumped.

I am using Arch linux and was trying to upgrade from the pacman version to gnuradio-git (https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/gnuradio-git).  Eventually figured out that I should also update osmosdr, which I used (https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/gr-osmosdr-git).  I think I actually am trying the non-free version of osmosdr now in attempts to correct this issue.  The problem I'm running into is in the python include (python v3.10):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/osmosdr/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from .osmosdr_python import *
ImportError: libgnuradio-runtime.so.3.9.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

This is the error I get using gnuradio-companion to try to generate a very simple FM receiver.  I've uninstalled an reinstalled gnuradio-git and gr-osmosdr-git in attempts to get it to find the correct version of libgnuradio-runtime (which is v3.11.0 located in the same folder /usr/lib)

I'm not good with python, and couldn't figure out how it was picking the version.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

I have installed `gnuradio-dev` packages and problem is resolved.

Have also a look here: [ModuleNotFoundError](https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/ModuleNotFoundError)

I am using DragonOS on PC and Kali on Raspberry.

Comment: I actually did solve this, but did it a while ago... I'm trying to remember what I did to fix it, but I ended up completely removed from Arch's packages to do it.